# Protocol message tag had invalid wire type

Tags: buffer, protocols, protocol-buffers

my application sends data through protobuf from a server to a client.
When I am deserializing the sent payload on the client side eclipse throws a expection of the follogwing type:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.google.protobuf.InvalidProtocolBufferException: Protocol message tag had invalid wire type.
```

The expection happens when I call "parseFrom()". I know that in most cases the error lies in a protobuf file with the wrong syntax. Therefore I hope that it is enough to post the protobuf definition here:

```
   package protobuf;

       option java_package = "com.carproject.abs.demo.protobuf";
       option java_outer_classname = "DesktopDevice_getCarsResponse";

    message CARS {

        required int64 carid = 1;
        required string carname = 2;

        message Carinformation {
            required string street = 1;
            required string postalcode = 2;
            required string city = 3;
            required string country = 4;
            required string cartimezoneid = 5;
        }

        message Right {
            optional string name = 1;
            optional int32 type = 2;
            optional int32 service = 3;
        }

        message PropertyType {
            optional string name = 1;
            optional string value = 2;
        }

        repeated Carinformation carinformation = 3; 
        repeated Right carrights = 4;
        repeated PropertyType carproperties = 5;
        repeated string inoid = 6;
    }
```

here is the code which shows how the data is written on the server side:

```
// carObj returns the necessary Strings
CAR carObj = car.getCAR();

Builder newBuilder = DesktopDevice_getCarResponse.CAR.newBuilder();

newBuilder.setCarid( carObj.getCARID() );
newBuilder.setCarname( carObj.getCARNAME());

// hardcoded values here
newBuilder.getCarinformationBuilder(1).setStreet( carObj.getCARNFORMATION().getSTREET() );
newBuilder.getCarinformationBuilder(1).setPostalcode( carObj.getCARINFORMATION().getPOSTALCODE() );
newBuilder.getCarinformationBuilder(1).setCity( carObj.getCARINFORMATION().getCITY() );
newBuilder.getCarinformationBuilder(1).setCountry( fleetObj.getCARINFORMATION().getCOUNTRY() );
newBuilder.getCarinformationBuilder(1).setCartimezoneid( fleetObj.getCARINFORMATION().getCARTIMEZONEID() );

byte[] responsePayload = newBuilder.build().toByteArray();
RestServerResponseMessage responseMsg = new RestServerResponseMessage( requestMsg.getRequestId(), responsePayload, "XML");
return responseMsg;
```

As you can see, the Server uses the Builder pattern provided by protobuf to set the necessary strings. Then the data is serialized as a byte[] and is sent back to the client via protobuf.

Here is the client code where I try to parse the data.

```
HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

    if (entity != null) {
        InputStream instream = entity.getContent();
        CAR car = DesktopDevice_getCarsResponse.CARS.parseFrom(instream);
        }
```

The exception is thrown when .parseFrom is called. Server code and carObj are working fine. I already sucessfully sending protobuf data in my program.

Comment: What does this have to do with REST?

Comment: I am also using REST in my application but thats not related to my problem here. Removed the tag

Comment: How did you write this data, **exactly**? was it using the same tool and the same .proto definition? Also: how did you physically do the writing? for example, a common error is to buffer in memory and then use the oversized part of the buffer (rather than just the part of the buffer with genuine protobuf data in it). I think we need to see the code that handles the reading and writing, more than we need to see the .proto...

Comment: edited my initial post with the coding on how the data is written on the server and on the client side.

Communication between the server and the client works via serialization as byte[] (successfullytested with another protobuf file) and carObj provides valid Strings for the protobuf-builder

Answer (score 3):

Use `Base64.getEncoder.encode(protoMsg.toByteArray)` on server. And use `Base64.getDecoder.decode(receivedArray[Bytes])`. Data sent on wire should always be encoded and decoded